# Java program that works like ATM

Tags: java

I'm trying to do a Java program that works like ATM. When I withdraw money from ATM, Java program needs to tell me how many banknotes I withdraw like if I take **2430 return should be 24 of 100 and 3 of 10** and ATM only **withdraws money in 10 20 50 100 euro banknotes**. How can I do it?

It looks like this:

```
 public class Withdraw
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int n=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    if(n>15000)
    {
      System.out.println("ATM Cash Limit exceeds.");
    }
    else
    {
      if(n<500)
      {
        System.out.println(n/100+" Hundreds");
      }
      else
      {
        int h=5;
        int f=(n-500)/500;
        //System.out.println(n-500+" "+(n-500)/500+" "+(n-500)%500);
        h += ((n-500)%500)/100;
        if(h>5)
        {
          f=f+1;
          h=h-5;
        }
        System.out.println(f+" Five Hundreds and "+h+" Hundreds");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. What is going wrong when you run the code you have provided? We need to know the expected and actual outputs, plus any error messages. Please edit the question accordingly. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below code must do the task for you including money withdrawal in 500,100,50,20,10,1.

```
public class Withdraw
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {

      int moneyValue=2430;
      int[] noteValues= {500,100,50,20,10,1};
      if(moneyValue>15000)
      {
          System.out.println("ATM Cash Limit exceeds.");
      }
      else
      {
         for(int i=0;i<noteValues.length && moneyValue!=0;i++)
         {
             if(moneyValue>=noteValues[i])
                 System.out.println("No of "+noteValues[i]+"'s"+" :"+moneyValue/noteValues[i]);
             moneyValue=moneyValue%noteValues[i];
         }
      }
  }
}   



 Output:
  No of 500's :4
  No of 100's :4
  No of 20's :1
  No of 10's :1
```

Comment: Thank you this was what im looking for.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to work backwards starting from the largest note:

```
//    n = 2430

int f = 0;
while (n >= 500) {
    f++;
    n -= 500;
}

int h= 0;
while (n >= 100) {
    h++;
    n -= 100;
}

// other values

System.out.println(f + " Five Hundreds and "+ h +" Hundreds" + ... );
```

Also, consider using well named variables.  For example, instead of `f`, name it something like `countOfFiveHundredEuroBankNotes`.

Also, extract the constants, for example:

```
private static final int FIVE_HUNDRED_EUROS = 500;
```

which helps make the code more readable:

```
int remainingRequestedAmount = n;

while (remainingRequestedAmount >= FIVE_HUNDRED_EUROS) {
    countOfFiveHundredEuroBankNotes++;
    remainingRequestedAmount -= FIVE_HUNDRED_EUROS;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could start with the largest bill amount and divide the money withdrawn. If that number is greater than 0, round it. That'll give you the quantity. You can then take away the quantity*billamount.

Than do the same to the next (as long as the amounts are in order from largest -> smallest)

E.G:

```
public class Withdraw
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        int moneyWithdrawn = 2040;
        final int[] amountsFromLargestToSmallest = { 100, 50, 20, 10};
        final int smallestBillAmount = 10;

        int[] amountsOfEachBill = new int[amountsFromLargestToSmallest.length];

        if (moneyWithdrawn > 15000)
        {
            System.out.println("ATM Cash Limit exceeds.");
        }
        // Must be divisible by 10, since that's our smallest bill
        else if (moneyWithdrawn <= 0 || moneyWithdrawn % 10 != 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter a valid number.");
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < amountsFromLargestToSmallest.length; i++)
            {
                int billAmount = amountsFromLargestToSmallest[i];

                int amount = (int) Math.floor(moneyWithdrawn / billAmount);

                if (amount > 0)
                {
                    moneyWithdrawn -= amount * billAmount;
                }

                amountsOfEachBill[i] = amount;
            }
        }
    }
}
```